# How to sign the android app to be preloaded on phone and not published on playstore to not get play protect block issue while installing?

Tags: android, block, preloading, google-play-protect

When we try to install the .apk which is signed by putting it in file manager of the phone and not published on playstore, we get an issue ,
 "**Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.**"
By clicking on "**Install anyway**", we are able to install the apk, but we don't want that pop up to come.
We need to preload the apk on a phone without publishing it.

We have done it in debug mode and face no issue, but when we did it in release mode and signed it, the issue arises. Also, from second time onwards, the issue is "**App not installed**".
We have seen all the solutions around the web in stack overflow, found a link to be similar, but the issue is different here. Since we do not have to publish it in the Google Playstore but preload on a phone, so the solution of publishing the app to not get this Play Protect issue will not work.

Expected : Play Protect block issue should not appear even if we don't publish it in Google Playstore.
Actual : We are facing Play Protect block issue when we signed the app and trying to sideload/preload the .apk .

Comment: how do you want to preload APK on device?

Comment: the apk is to be preinstalled on a phone a new batch of which is to be released.

Comment: how exactly is it preloaded?

Comment: a new phone that is to be launched will have the app preinstalled( he can see the icon of the app along with other default apps that come with the phone) when buying the phone. That app will be in the fresh batch of the phone but will not be available in The Google Play Store.
Say we have to install the signed apk from a folder in the phone and not download it from the play store.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable Google Play Protected form Google Play store and it will not ask anymore. Hear is the link that shows how to disable play protected, 
[How to disable Google Play Protected?](https://support.mobile-tracker-free.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005346953-How-to-disable-Google-Play-Protect-)

Comment: Disabling Google Play Protect is the client's(user's) choice. As a developer , we cant make the client's disable their play protect settings.